Wifi fails with CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED after several days
I have a computer that's set up as a server on my home wifi network running linux. I can connect it to the Wifi but it will disconnect after several days of operation and journalctl fills up with messages like:
 Jun 18 19:14:00 server wpa_supplicant[1258]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Is this likely to be a hardware issue with the wifi adapter? I have another computer in a similar configuration that doesn't have this problem. What other steps can I take to debug? It is the in-built Wifi adapter on an ASUS PRIME-B650M-A-WIFI-II motherboard

Try disabling any Ethernet adapters you might have

@Ramhound this seems to have solved it. Thanks!!

I disabled all the ethernet interfaces, and the computer has been accessible over Wi-Fi for 10 days now.
